# Which one is correct formula?

Tags: articles, time

Why " all the day" is correct here
and when we use "all the day"?[image]

Comment: I think you mean *why **all day** is correct*. Well, those expressions are fixed, they carry no article, that's why the book shows the nouns *morning, afternoon, evening, night*, etc. being used with no article.

Comment: I need more explanation

Comment: Here is the answer, it can't get better than this: http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/8981077611

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"All", when applied to periods of time to refer to something that happened throughout the whole time period, does not use articles in front of the period of time.

> What were you doing **all night**?
>
> Gilligan stayed at his cottage **all week**.
>
> I'd party **all day** instead of going to school.

I have never encountered a person using "All the day".

As to why, I don't think that has an answer. Some languages (e.g. French) use an article here, some don't. That's how it goes.